# Como optimizar busqueda de arreglos de bytes duplicados en C#?

Tags: c#, algoritmos, linq

Tengo la siguiente lista de Objetos:

```
List<PacketData> packetList = new List<PacketData>();

public class PacketData{
    public DateTime timestamp {get; set;}
    public byte[] data {get; set;}
    public bool isDuplicated {get; set;}
}
```

De esa lista tengo que eliminar todos los `data` duplicados en un rango de tiempo basado en el `timestamp`.

Para eliminar los duplicados hide lo siguiente (funciona, pero siento que el rendimiento no es el optimo):

```
//creo una lista para guardar el resultado
List<PacketData> newListPackets = new List<PacketData>();

//recorro la lista original
foreach (var packet in packetList)
{
    //si el paquete no esta duplicado
    if (!packet.isDuplicated )
    {
        //hago la busqueda utilizando LINQ
        packetList.Where(
                (p, k) =>
                    //paquetes que no esten duplicados
                    !p.isDuplicated  &&
                    //donde la diferencia de tiempo sea menor a un segundo
                    Math.Abs((packet.timestamp  - p.timestamp ).TotalSeconds) < 1 &&
                    //y que el paquete (arreglo de bytes) sean iguales
                    p.data.SequenceEqual(packet.data)
            ).Select(p =>
            {
                //el resultado, los marco como duplicados
                p.isDuplicated  = true;
                return p;
            }).ToList();

        newListPackets.Add(packet);
    }
}
```

He utilizado otros metodos pero este es el mas eficiente hasta el momento.
Con un total de 46,633 elementos en la lista me da un tiempo de procesamiento de 6 minutos con 16 segundos.

De antemanos gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: El problema se ve interesante, pero la lógica no está clara. Dices que deseas eliminar los "duplicados", pero yo veo lo opuesto en el código. Veo que acumulas en tu nueva lista precisamente los packets que marcas como duplicados. Adicionalmente, la lógica con el timestamp no está del todo claro. Creo que la lógica requiere mas explicación, idealmente, con ejemplos concretos.

Comment: no, acumulo el `packet` pivote, el del `foreach`, los demas que encontre repetidos a el los marco como duplicados, asi cuando el `foreach` los alcance lo valido con el `if (!packet.isDuplicated )` si da `true` simplemente paso al siguiente paquete.

Comment: Ok, ahora entiendo, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que afecta tu rendimiento es que para cada paquete en el `foreach` haces un `Where`, lo que equivale a escanear toda la lista. Es cierto que eventualmente evitas considerar los ya marcados duplicados, pero asumo que esos son la minoría, por lo que de modo general, me imagino que para una lista de 46,333 paquetes, te toca hacer aproximadamente (46,333 x 46,333) 2,146,746,889 iteraciones.

Otro problema es que, en cada iteración del `foreach`, estás creando una lista que en realidad no usas, sino que solo lo usas para asegurarte de que se ejecute el código en el `Select()`, donde modificas la propiedad `isDuplicated`. Esto, no solamente es costoso, pero en realidad es un abuso de LINQ, ya que no está diseñado para *modificar* datos cómo lo haces.

Aprovecho para mencionar que aunque LINQ es fantástico para expresar código de forma bien compacta y legible, hay que tener cuidado con imaginarse que solo porque hay menos líneas de código, que esto automáticamente significa que el rendimiento es mejor. De hecho, aun usado correctamente, el uso de LINQ típicamente empeora el rendimiento. Pero en la mayoría de los casos, la diferencia es negligible y vale la pena para poder simplificar el código.

Te propongo de probar un algoritmo que ordena tu lista por fecha para comenzar. Una vez ordenados por fecha, puedes aprovechar esto para no tener que iterar la lista entera dentro del bucle. Mas bien, puedes detener la búsqueda enseguida cuando te topas con un paquete que está a un segundo o más en el futuro. Como la lista está ordenada, sabes que no da nada continuar buscando después que eso sucede.  Esto debería reducir considerablemente la cantidad total de iteraciones y la cantidad de veces que necesitas hacer la comparación de bytes.

```
var newListPackets = new List<PacketData>();
var orderedPacketList = packetList; //.OrderBy(p => p.timestamp).ToList(); -- no necesitas esto si la lista ya está ordenada.
for (int x = 0; x < orderedPacketList.Count; x++)
{
    var packetX = orderedPacketList[x];
    bool isDuplicate = false;
    for (int y = x + 1; y < orderedPacketList.Count; y++)
    {
        var packetY = orderedPacketList[y];
        if ((packetY.timestamp - packetX.timestamp).TotalSeconds >= 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (packetX.data.SequenceEqual(packetY.data))
        {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isDuplicate)
    {
        newListPackets.Add(packetX);
    }
}
```

De paso, notarás que el algoritmo no usa ni necesita que definas una propiedad `isDuplicated` en tu clase `PacketData`.

**Edición**

Quité el `OrderBy` siendo que en el comentario abajo mencionas que la lista ya está ordenada por `timestamp`.

Comment: La lista ya viene ordenada por el timestamp.
Esa solucion que propones fue la primera que hice, igual sin el while, pero con la misma logica que me dices y el tiempo era de mas de 30 minutos.

Comment: Me cuesta creer que este algoritmo tome mas tiempo que la de la pregunta. Si puedes probar mi código exactamente como lo tengo y ver cuanto tiempo toma, lo apreciaré.

Comment: eso estoy haciendo, se reduce considerablemente el tiempo y la cantidad de paquetes en resultado... ando checando cuales son las diferencias, por que en la logica es identica a la mia. Muchas gracias de antemano, voy a revisar,

Comment: En efecto, hay una diferencia muy sutil entre este algoritmo, y la que tienes en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes paquetes con `data` idénticos con los timestamps siguientes: `00:00:00.500, 00:00:00.900, 00:00:01.400, 00:00:02.100`. Con el algoritmo de la pregunta, entiendo que te quedará `00:00:00.500, 00:00:02.100` en la lista final, mientras que en la mía solo se quedará con `00:00:02.100`. No tengo espacio para explicar el porqué de la diferencia, pero te diré que sin una mayor explicación de cómo esperabas comparar con los timestamps, técnicamente mi resultado me parece válido

Comment: Si eso lo comprendo, me refiero que antes de cambiar a linq lo tenia muy parecido a tu solución y no me daba el rendimiento que da el tuyo

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿cuanto tiempo tomó?

Comment: aproximadamente 4 segundos. Gracias